# Por qué obtengo dos hash distintas?

Tags: linux, terminal, hash, md5

a partir de la frase MASTEROFPUPPETS quiero generar el hash asociado a través del algoritmo MD5

Si utilizo el comando:

```
echo -n MASTEROFPUPPETS | md5sum > md5.txt
```

> El resultado obtenido es: f395885371dd0ad12136d8a733e05e22

Pero si lo quiero leer de un fichero tal que así:

```
cat upper.txt | md5sum > md5.txt
```

El resultado obtenido es:

> 92216173e4ecf470008cb11ef008529d

Añadir que en upper.txt tengo MASTEROFPUPPETS

¿Por qué? ¿De que manera podría leer directamente del fichero para no tener que ponerlo a mano?

Gracias!

Comment: Ese es el objetivo de un hash, que no puedas volverlo a decodificar. Solo puedes comprobarlo. Si deseas volver a ver lo que se encripto debes de hacer eso. Encriptar lo.

Answer (score 1):

Si el hash de lo que le pasamos a *md5sum* varía, significa que recibió
dos cosas distintas.

Analicemos el contenido de *upper.txt* pero **mirando sus bytes**. Para
eso podemos usar el comando *od*:

```
$ od -x --endian=big upper.txt
0000000 4d41 5354 4552 4f46 5055 5050 4554 530a
0000020
```

Podemos ignorar la primera columna. En las demas columnas, cada una tiene
dos bytes del archivo en hexadecimal, por ejemplo, 4d y 41, que corresponden a
los caracteres 'M' y 'A' (podes ver la correspondencia en la tabla ascii con
`$ man ascii`).

El texto original (MASTEROFPUPPETS) tiene 15 caracteres, sin embargo en el
archivo tenemos 16 bytes. ¿Qué pasa?. El ultimo caracter lo suelen agregar los
editores de texto para indicar el fin de una linea. Es el caracter de nueva linea
y en hexadecimal es 0a.

En el comando:

```
$ echo -n MASTEROFPUPPETS
```

Se llama a *echo* con *-n*, lo que hace que al imprimir MASTEROFPUPPETS no le
agregue un caracter de nueva linea. De ahí que los *hashes* te den distintos.